Как правильно выводить посты по категориям с помощью ACF?
Есть сайт блог на WP+AFC,мне нужно создать посты по категориям и вывести их на разных страницах в зависимости от категории + сделать вывод related posts внизу страницы.Как создать эти карточки(превью) постов и выводить их в произвольных местах(даже на главной) и что бы по нажатию они вели на созданные мной отдельные страницы с самим текстом?

ACF Relationship
